# Vraptor task nao funciona

Tags: java, vraptor

Estou tendo um problema com o vraptor task. Tenho um projeto Vraptor 4 criado que esta enviando email normalmente, porem quando tento criar uma tarefa não envia email. Veja a classe da task

Controller

```
public class EntrevistaTask {

private final EmailJava email;

@Inject
public EntrevistaTask(EmailJava email){
this.email = email;
}

@Deprecated
public EntrevistaTask(){
this(null);
}

Scheduled(cron="0/30 * * * * ?")
public void avisoEntrevista() throws EmailException{
email.enviarEmail("jobvision@informaticars.com.br", "Nova vaga", "Vaga cadastrada com sucesso", "jobvision@informaticars.com.br");
}

}
```

Obrigados a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Na linha:

```
Scheduled(cron="0/30 * * * * ?")
```

Você deve colocar o @, dessa forma:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0/30 * * * * ?")
```

Considerando que o envio de e-mails funciona normalmente, só essa alteração já deve fazer seu código funcionar!

Espero ter ajudado,